# Spring cachable with multiple nodes

Tags: java, spring, caching

In my application I'm using spring's cache. But now I want to scale the application to multiple nodes with a load-balancer. What is the recommended solution to evict/update cache on multiple nodes?

Answer (score 1):

Look at http://terracotta.org/documentation/3.7.4/enterprise-ehcache/configuration-guide#95592 for Tomcat

Or http://infinispan.org/docs/5.3.x/getting_started/getting_started.html on Jboss.